# How can I configure TortoiseHg Workbench to use the --subrepos switch

Tags: tortoisehg, mercurial-subrepos

I'd like to know how I can configure TortoiseHg Workbench so it alawys supplies the `--subrepos` switch when checking status. I can do this with the commandline no problem. I only need to do this for this 1 repository - it is the only repo that has a subrepo.

- root

  - folder 1
  - folder 2
  - folder 3 (this is a subrepo)

In TortoiseHg Workbench if I'm at the root level and I'm on the commit tab, I press the refresh file list icon and it will show me the status for everything except in the subrepo... Not what I want, I want to know that there are changes in that subrepo.

Even when I commit it is excluding new files, it doesn't see them as added. It will commit any changes, but not new files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using TortoiseHg 2.3.1.  In the commit window:

[image]

Comment: And don't forget "Save in repo"

Comment: @LazyBadger can you elaborate on what effect that has?

Comment: @SimonMartin - save setting on this checkbox in order to don't enable it in *this repo* every time on every commit. Really this answer make my previous hint about aliasing redundant and obsolete